# Postgresql trigger to update a column in a table when another table same column gets updated

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have 2 tables as follows

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id serial PRIMARY key,
  first_name VARCHAR(100),
  last_name VARCHAR(100),
  dob date
);

CREATE TABLE providers (
  provider_id INTEGER,
  first_name VARCHAR(100),
  last_name VARCHAR(100),
  user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users (user_id),
  address TEXT
);
```

I want a trigger on table users to update the first_name, last_name fields whenever the data in the providers table is updated. I am trying to find out what is the best way to achieve this.

FYI: the reason i am going through this route is because i have a generated column in providers table using first_name and last_name.

I tried to update the users table in my application but i am hoping there must be an easier way for me to update the users table w/o touching it in the front end. Any ideas?

Comment: Just check the manual and get started: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html

Comment: Why should changing the providers name change the users name?

Comment: Why did you not include the generated column in `providers`? You're much more likely to get useful answers if you provide all of the relevant details. If `providers(user_id, first_name, last_name)` is the same as `users(user_id, first_name, last_name)`, then the design isn't in third-normal form. Instead of replicating data between tables and using generated columns, consider using views. Using triggers to keep values synchronized between tables often  adds unnecessary complexity and introduces many opportunities to introduce code defects.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't log in so couldn't reply sooner. My goal is to add a generated column in providers table by using columns from users table. As per the postgresql documentation, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html   The generation expression can refer to other columns in the table, but not other generated columns. Any functions and operators used must be immutable. References to other tables are not allowed.